# Factory style pattern in method

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a method in a class, and its sole purpose is to prepare another class for use:

```
private function createHttpPost($endPoint) {
    $httpPost = new HttpPost($this->baseUri . '/' . $endPoint);
    $httpPost->setContentType('application/json');
    $httpPost->setAccept('application/json');

    if($this->auth) {
        $this->authenticate();
        $httpPost->addCookies(array($this->sessionName => $this->sessionId));
        $httpPost->addHeaders(array('X-CSRF-Token' => $this->token));
    }

    return $httpPost;
}
```

I am familiar with the factory design pattern, but I'm not sure it is a good idea to apply that kind of thinking to a class method. Should I take this code out and put it in a new class called `JsonHttpPostFactory`, or something like that?

Is this a bad idea?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

In itself, there's nothing wrong with this code. There really isn't. But there are some things you need to consider:

- The method is `private`, so it's an internal kind of factory, why not use a lazy-loading getter?
- The method is `private`, that makes this method a dead-end in a scenario where, for example, the content-type needs to be changed
- If you have access to the `HttpPost` class, why not add a method `setEndPoint`, so you don't need to create a new instance time and time again

On the whole, I'd start with changing the access modifier to `protected`, so that in a child class, you can do something like:

```
protected function createHttpPost($endPoint, array $options = null)
{
    if ($options === null)//default, use parent version
        return parent::createHttpPost($endPoint);
    $httpPost = new HttpPost($this->baseUri.'/'.$endPoint);
    $httpPost->setContentType($options['contentType'])
        ->setAccept($options['accept']);
    //and so on...
}
```

If you can alter the `HttpPost` class, I'd also encourage you to add methods that reset the instance to a pristine state (a state that allows another request). Then you can lazy-load this instance as a property, and reuse it:

```
protected function createHttpPost($endPoint, array $options)
{
    $httpPost = $this->getHttpPost();//see below
    $httpPost->setContentType($options['contentType'])
        ->setAccept($options['accept'])
        ->setEndPoint($this->baseUri.'/'.$endPoint);
    //and so on
}
/**
 * Lazy-loader for HttpPost instance
 * @return HttpPost
 */
protected function getHttpPost()
{
    if ($this->httpPost === null)
        $this->httpPost = new HttpPost;
    else
        $this->httpPost->resetInstance();
    return $this->httpPost;
}
```

This way, the constructor will only be called once, and only when the instance of `HttpPost` is required. Then, you can re-use the instance for each request.
If the instance of `HttpPost` is passed around, or a request is not made instantaneously, then there could be a risk of this request object losing its state, before a request is made. If this is possible, then of course, you don't use a lazy-loader like the one above, but just use a getter function, or keep doing what you do (ie: create an instance ad-hoc).

Comment: I feel like this kind of of design could lead to issues. I think it's best to have a single instance of HttpRequest per endpoint. What happens if the lazy-loaded instance gets reset mid-request?

Comment: @CameronBall: The `createHttpPost` method isn't public, so the request instance is returned inside the class instance itself. So I sort of assumed the request is made by the class itself, too.

Comment: Yes, it is in this case. What you've said makes sense in the context of this class. But in a general context you could have problems with the HttpPost's state getting unintentionally reset, no? This class is shared between other entities as well.

Comment: @CameronBall: Yes, that is a possible issue, but again: if the instance is created and returned back to the instance where this method resides, when a request is made, then it is not possible for the state to be reset elsewhere (no concurrency). Either way, I've added a note to my answer